# button renders but callbacks aren't called

Tags: javascript, html, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

```
function renderButton() {
  gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
    'scope': 'profile email',
    'width': 240,
    'height': 50,
    'longtitle': true,
    'theme': 'light',
    'onsuccess': onSuccess,
    'onfailure': onFailure
  });
}

function onFailure() {
  console.log('why the');
}

function onSuccess(googleUser) {
  console.log('onSuccess has been called');
}
```

The button is rendered correctly but neither of the callback methods are called.

How can I call `onSuccess` after the button loads?

Comment: Try adding brackets when calling the functions `'onsuccess': onSuccess()`

Comment: You are not calling the function. You are just adding the reference.

Comment: @Shubham what do you mean?

Comment: It should be just the reference, or you're assigning the result of executing the callbacks, which is wrong.  Adding the brackets is wrong.

Comment: @Dumisani  you have to provide the functions without brackets because they are used as callbacks by google

Comment: Yes - 100% correct.  The problem lies elsewhere.  Do you get anything insightful in the browser console?

Comment: This is not because you define your callbacks after ?

Comment: Alright, noted :)

Comment: @Epitouille when using the `function name() {}` constructor the position of it doesn't matter, it is defined before all other javascript runs

Comment: @Archer nothing at all is logged to the console (apart from a 'Popper missing' error thrown by bootstrap, but I don't think this is related)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I've been an idiot.

onSuccess and onFailure are callbacks for whether the user logged in successfully or not.

I thought they'd be called after the button rendered successfully.

So now I need to find out how I can run some code after the button renders.